# C# razorengine for templates how to write if statement

Tags: razorengine

https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine

I am using this RazorEngine to generate emails like:

> Hi {%=Firstname%} {%=Lastname%},

now I would like to check if Firstname and Lastname are not empty

I try like:

> @if (Firstname != '' || Lastname != '') { Hi, } else  {
>   Hi{%=Firstname%} {%=Lastname%}, }

but does not work. if statement is printed as HTML